# Server isn't reachable after hours running

Tags: networking

Like in the title descriped. Normally I need to talk with my VPS provider but they heller stupid, they know NOTHING about linux and they test from there own Network which ofc always work.

My server is already reinstalled 3 times because of this problem, but as I found out Im not responsible for it. Because a fresh installation of Ubuntu should be reachable even after 12 hours running! But this isn't the case on my VPS.

I have nothing showing in my logsn, no errors. The services stopped to work at certain time. Like 10am you can't reach the apache2 or SSH service, but they are running, I can connect over KVM. Firewall is inactive

Which logs do you need or do I have to look into?
This is the latest syslog entry after the services were unreachable:

```
Feb  2 21:49:19 fs dbus-daemon[921]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.145' (uid=0 pid=1>
Feb  2 21:49:19 fs systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Feb  2 21:49:19 fs PackageKit: daemon start
Feb  2 22:09:07 fs systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
```

Version:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"